# MySQL: Average OF Subquerys (NOT in the FROM/GROUP BY)

Tags: mysql, average

I want to show the average prices of product groups of my database. Therefore I want to return the average price of all of the products within that product group over time.

First of all, I want to know how many price changes for that group there has been. This query successfully returns all of the dates, with this query...

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(gbp.prdate)) as dte
FROM sku AS s
  INNER JOIN mt_price gbp ON s.id = gbp.
WHERE (gbp.prdate < NOW() - INTERVAL ? DAY) AND (s.grp = ?)`
```

Then I use a foreach within php to generate the following query...

```
$i = 1;
$qry = "SELECT s.id AS sid, s.sku, s.title AS s_title,";
foreach ($dates as $date) {
  $qry .= "(SELECT price FROM price WHERE price.sid = s.id AND prdate <= DATE(?) ORDER BY prdate LIMIT 1) AS ?, ";
  $datearr[] = $date;
}
$qry = substr($qry, 0, -2) . " ";
$qry .= "FROM sku AS s
  WHERE (s.grp = ?)
  GROUP BY s.id
  ORDER BY s.id";
$results = $db->prepare($qry);
foreach($datearr as $darr) {
  $results->bindParam($i++,$darr->dte,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $results->bindParam($i++,$darr->dte,PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

One example of the above gives me this query...

```
SELECT s.id AS sid, s.rid, s.sku, s.title AS s_title,
  (SELECT price FROM price WHERE price.sid = s.id AND prdate <= DATE('2015-01-08') ORDER BY prdate LIMIT 1) AS '2015-01-08',
  (SELECT price FROM price WHERE price.sid = s.id AND prdate <= DATE('2015-02-12') ORDER BY prdate LIMIT 1) AS '2015-02-12',
  (SELECT price FROM price WHERE price.sid = s.id AND prdate <= DATE('2015-01-26') ORDER BY prdate LIMIT 1) AS '2015-01-26',
  (SELECT price FROM price WHERE price.sid = s.id AND prdate <= DATE('2015-02-08') ORDER BY prdate LIMIT 1) AS '2015-02-08',
  (SELECT price FROM price WHERE price.sid = s.id AND prdate <= DATE('2015-01-30') ORDER BY prdate LIMIT 1) AS '2015-01-30',
  (SELECT price FROM price WHERE price.sid = s.id AND prdate <= DATE('2015-02-02') ORDER BY prdate LIMIT 1) AS '2015-02-02'
```

FROM sku AS s
    WHERE (s.cat = 'TLPT01')
    GROUP BY s.id
    ORDER BY s.id

When I run this query as the above, I get what I would expect, only one price per SKU (down to the `LIMIT`) and the correct price at that. It will then display the price of the SKU correctly as the `DATE` changes. Yay me!

So, what I want is to get the average of all of these results. If I use `AVG` in front of `s.id` I get an average of the SKUs, this is obviously not a result that means anything. I want the average price for all of the SKUs returned (and therefore, the `GROUP BY` should only give me one row of information). When I put `GROUP BY` before the subqueries, I just get an error.

Comment: Please post the full SQL string from `$qry` after it is built up in the loop, as it is difficult to see what it becomes. Also, post a sample of input rows from the tables involved, and a sample of what you would expect the query output to be. It's important to develop your queries outside of and entirely detached from the PHP code.  It will be much easier to develop and debug the query without all the PHP code and param binding in the way.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

You're not coding what you're saying; *the average of each datel*. Use a avg query over a sub query (simplified):

```
select date, avg(avg_price) from (
    select group_id, date, avg(price) avg_price
    from mytable
    group by group_id, date
) x
group by date
```

The inner query will produce one avg value per group_ id and date, and the outer query averages those group_id/date values just by date.

Comment: Although to be precise this is the average of the date averages, not of the group.  E.g. if one date has 1 value and the other date have 3 values, the outer average will only be averaging 2 values (first date and second date).  Whether this matters depends what level of accuracy is required and the range of values.

Comment: I think my question (it was late!) wasn'y put the correct way. I have edited my question. i want the average price for each date, so each subquery.

Comment: @themrflibble I changed the abbreviated quest to average by date - is that helpful? Can you try your code with this idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the subquery as follows
    (SELECT AVG(price) FROM price WHERE price.sid = s.id AND prdate <= DATE(?) GROUP BY price.sid)

Comment: I had tried this, and it gives the average price for the duration of that SKU. The reason I have done the `PHP foreach` is that I want columns of the price at that time (hence multiple subqueries), and then to return the average of this column (and all other columns).

Answer (score 0):

I found that moving the subquery into a `LEFT JOIN` the solution. I could then do an `AVG` on prices returned from these JOINs. I still do not know why I couldn't just `AVG` the subqueries, but this method (although is not super quick)... works.

```
SELECT s.cat, s.id AS sid, s.rid, s.sku, s.title AS s_title, AVG(pr1.price)
FROM sku AS s
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT sid, price, prdate FROM price WHERE prdate <= DATE('2014-12-21') ) AS pr1 ON s.id = pr1.sid
  ... <more from foreach, add more AVG on top line> ...
WHERE (s.cat = 'TLPT01')
GROUP BY cat
```